# Strange garbage in subprocess.stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Why does the following Python script

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['time', 'ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print(p.stderr.readline().decode('utf-8'))
```

outputs the following:

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2264maxresident)k
```

while `time ls` command outputs the following:

```
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.000s
```

what is this strange suffix `91%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2264maxresident)k?`

The script should read the first line and parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` command you use in the shell is a shell builtin while the `time` in the python subprocess refer to `/usr/bin/time`. They are NOT the same. Here is the [manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) where you can find the GNU time command in which you can see the meaning of the suffix.

Comment: Use `command time ls` to get the external command (`/usr/bin/time`) in the shell.

Comment: To get the shell built-in `time` command, use `subprocess.Popen('time ls', shell=True)`.